# File Storage Synchronization Local Service

Tags: windows, osx, file-management, file-synchronization, centos-7

I want to install a Local Service on my Network like: Google Drive/OneDrive, etc for File Storage and Synchronization .

I have Windows 7/10, macOS, CentOS 6/7 and I want the client for this tool/service.

Thank you for your recommendations.

Comment: if you are talking about syncing with a central server, maybe [Nextcloud](https://nextcloud.com/) with its clients is worth a look. i use it for syncing not just files...

Answer (score 2):

My experience is with [FreeFileSync](https://www.freefilesync.org) and it runs on Win/Mac/Linux.

You can synchronize cloud storage via SFTP and also FTP and MTP protocols are supported.

On each version is getting better, and you can launch from script with several configuration options.

Too there is a portable version.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [Allway Sync](https://allwaysync.com/) for some time. I'd been using it primarily for backup purposes but recently took advantage of the ability to synchronize with my host via FTP. I searched the [feature list](https://allwaysync.com/features) for references to Google Drive. There are not explicit references to Google Drive, but the [update list](https://allwaysync.com/news) shows that Google Drive problems have been corrected. The precise wording is

> Reworked Amazon Cloud Drive, Google Drive, OneDrive synchronization engines;

The download is free and it appears only Windows machines are supported, although with the use of a [Mac Sync Gateway](https://allwaysync.com/sync-gateway), one can also involve files stored on a Mac computer. The free version works in the same manner as the paid version, but will eventually call you out for using it too much, if their interpretation of occasional use is exceeded.

The flexibility of the program is tremendous. Configuration of numerous jobs is relatively simple, yet can be adjusted in so many ways.

I have no association with the company, just a regular and frequently satisified user.

UPDATE: It appears that I've misread your query. You are asking for clients for specific services rather than a synchronization program. Just as a split-off, I performed a search for "install google one drive on network" and found a number of different work-arounds to accomplish this objective. Almost all of them require a third-party application. I did not search for similar wording regarding MS OneDrive, but suspect the results will be similar.

Allway Sync will work well in that respect, depending on your server configuration, I suspect. It's an inexpensive third party application with support for these services.